# Angular 6 - Object Properties Updating without Setting them

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an editor where the user can edit a product. I save an instance of the product in `ngOnInit` under `initialProduct` to make it possible to reset the edits.

Unfortunately, I have a weird issue: **When adding a new tag the properties of the `initialProduct` changes without setting them.**

Here is a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxrh2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code

```
this.initialProduct = this.product;
```

you are assigning to `this.initialProduct` the same variable positioned at the memory index related by `this.product`. This because `this.product` points to a memory address and with the previous operation you are copying only the memory address. So `this.product` and `this.initialProduct` point to the same variable.

You need to create another array and to copy `this.product` values into `this.initialProduct` (new array).

You can do this by various ways. For example:

```
    // this.initialProduct = this.product;
    this.initialProduct = {
      tags: Array.from(this.product.tags)
    }
```

or

```
    // this.initialProduct = this.product;
    this.initialProduct = {
      tags: this.product.tags.concat()
    }
```

or

```
    // this.initialProduct = this.product;
    this.initialProduct = {
      tags: this.product.tags.slice()
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know this :D Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

because of references

```
this.tags = this.product.tags;
```

You can do the following (ES6):

```
this.tags = [...this.product.tags];
```